# Verneinung vor einer modalen Angabe

Tags: word-order, negation, modal-particle, position

Ich habe im Internet gelesen, dass das Wort "nicht" vor modalen Angaben gestellt werden sollte.
Zum Beispiel:

> Ich sehe nicht gerne fern.

Ich habe Zweifel, ob bei Fällen wie im Beispiel der ganze Satz verneint wird, oder nur die bestimmte modale Angabe. Falls die zweite Möglichkeit passt, wird ein "sondern" gefordert? Und wenn die erste Möglichkeit passt, wäre es auch richtig, wenn ich sage:

> *Ich sehe gerne fern nicht.

Comment: Ich denke dein Beispiel passt schon nicht, da dort keine modale Angabe, Modalsatz, Modalverb oder Ähnliches vorkommt. Evtl solltest du die Frage überarbeiten, bzw präzisieren. "Gerne" ist hier zunächst einmal ein Adverb oder worauf willst du hinaus?

Comment: @mtwde https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angabe_%28Grammatik%29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es kommt ganz einfach darauf an, *was* verneint werden soll, und daraus ergibt sich die Position der Verneinung.

1. *Ich sehe nicht gerne fern* - Hier wird der gesamte Satz verneint, das Prädikat und die Modalität. Der Sprecher meint, dass er es nicht mag, auf dem Sofa zu sitzen und fernzusehen.
2. *Ich sehe gerne nicht fern* - ist durchaus möglich, die Modalität ist von der Verneinung ausgenommen, der Sprecher sagt, dass er gerne vor ausgeschaltetem Fernseher auf dem Sofa sitzt.

Andere Positionen für "nicht" sind in deinem Beispiel nicht möglich.